# MySQL - Use Alias ​inside WHERE clause with GREATEST

Tags: sql, mysql, if-statement

I have a query in MySQL, and I'm currently using sorting as follows:

```
ORDER BY total_numbers_line_1 DESC, total_numbers_line_2 DESC, total_numbers_line_3 DESC
```

However, I need to use GREATEST, which should look something like:

```
ORDER BY GREATEST(total_numbers_line_1, total_numbers_line_2, total_numbers_line_3);
```

However, MySQL does not accept it, as the fields provided are ALIAS of three SUM clauses. Is there a way to do this? I need the highest value among the three aliases to be considered in ordering.

I already tried using the Greatest, the IF and the When, and none of them worked

My actual query is, this work is for my Work College, I had the "brilliant" idea to build an online lottery system:

```sql
SELECT *,
  SUM(IF(FIND_IN_SET('21', numbers_line1), 1 ,0) +
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('15', numbers_line1), 1 ,0) +
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('43', numbers_line1), 1 ,0) +
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('42', numbers_line1), 1 ,0) +
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('78', numbers_line1), 1 ,0) +
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('4', numbers_line1), 1 ,0) +
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('27', numbers_line1), 1 ,0)
  ) AS total_numbers_line_1,
  SUM(IF(FIND_IN_SET('21', numbers_line2), 1 ,0) +
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('15', numbers_line2), 1 ,0) +
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('43', numbers_line2), 1 ,0) +
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('42', numbers_line2), 1 ,0) +
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('78', numbers_line2), 1 ,0) +
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('4', numbers_line2), 1 ,0) +
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('27', numbers_line2), 1 ,0)
  ) AS total_numbers_line_2,
  SUM(IF(FIND_IN_SET('21', numbers_line3), 1 ,0) +
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('15', numbers_line3), 1 ,0) +
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('43', numbers_line3), 1 ,0) +
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('42', numbers_line3), 1 ,0) +
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('78', numbers_line3), 1 ,0) +
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('4', numbers_line3), 1 ,0) +
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('27', numbers_line3), 1 ,0)
  ) AS total_numbers_line_3
FROM cards
WHERE id_bingo = '64e3da663a617'
GROUP BY
    id_card
HAVING
    total_numbers_line_1 > 0
    OR total_numbers_line_2 > 0
    OR total_numbers_line_3 > 0 
ORDER BY total_numbers_line_1 DESC,
  total_numbers_line_2 DESC,
  total_numbers_line_3 DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  So you want to order by 1 column instead of 3?

Comment: Are you trying to use `greatest` and aliases in your `order by` clause (like your question text) or in your `where` clause (like your title)? If in the `order by` clause, I think it should work: https://dbfiddle.uk/xG8RyZ59

Comment: `greatest` also should't be a problem in your `where` clause, although the aliases won't work there. If they're aggregates you could probably move to your `having` clause.

Comment: I edit my question, and put the full SQL to help you to help me :)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you get an error when you change your query to use `greatest` in the `order by`? If so, what is it?

Comment: Please post your expected output and your actual output. A wild guess: Are you trying to order the columns rather than the rows, so that the highest of your numbers is left-most?

Answer (score 0):

Use subquery to order by the greatest of 3 columns in a row:

```sql
SELECT id_bingo, id_card,
  total_numbers_line_1,
  total_numbers_line_2,
  total_numbers_line_3,
  GREATEST(total_numbers_line_1, total_numbers_line_2, total_numbers_line_3) AS greatest_total
FROM (
  SELECT id_bingo, id_card,
    numbers_line1,
    numbers_line2,
    numbers_line3,
    SUM(
      IF(FIND_IN_SET('21', numbers_line1), 1 , 0) +
      IF(FIND_IN_SET('15', numbers_line1), 1 , 0) +
      IF(FIND_IN_SET('43', numbers_line1), 1 , 0) +
      IF(FIND_IN_SET('42', numbers_line1), 1 , 0) +
      IF(FIND_IN_SET('78', numbers_line1), 1 , 0) +
      IF(FIND_IN_SET('4', numbers_line1), 1 , 0) +
      IF(FIND_IN_SET('27', numbers_line1), 1 , 0)
    ) AS total_numbers_line_1,
    SUM(
      IF(FIND_IN_SET('21', numbers_line2), 1 , 0) +
      IF(FIND_IN_SET('15', numbers_line2), 1 , 0) +
      IF(FIND_IN_SET('43', numbers_line2), 1 , 0) +
      IF(FIND_IN_SET('42', numbers_line2), 1 , 0) +
      IF(FIND_IN_SET('78', numbers_line2), 1 , 0) +
      IF(FIND_IN_SET('4', numbers_line2), 1 , 0) +
      IF(FIND_IN_SET('27', numbers_line2), 1 , 0)
    ) AS total_numbers_line_2,
    SUM(
      IF(FIND_IN_SET('21', numbers_line3), 1 , 0) +
      IF(FIND_IN_SET('15', numbers_line3), 1 , 0) +
      IF(FIND_IN_SET('43', numbers_line3), 1 , 0) +
      IF(FIND_IN_SET('42', numbers_line3), 1 , 0) +
      IF(FIND_IN_SET('78', numbers_line3), 1 , 0) +
      IF(FIND_IN_SET('4', numbers_line3), 1 , 0) +
      IF(FIND_IN_SET('27', numbers_line3), 1 , 0)
    ) AS total_numbers_line_3
  FROM cards
  WHERE id_bingo = '64e3da663a617'
  GROUP BY id_card
  HAVING total_numbers_line_1 > 0
    OR total_numbers_line_2 > 0
    OR total_numbers_line_3 > 0 
  ORDER BY total_numbers_line_1 DESC,
    total_numbers_line_2 DESC,
    total_numbers_line_3 DESC
  LIMIT 20
  ) AS tbl
ORDER BY greatest_total DESC;
```

Comment: The "total_line_numbers_x" is not columms, is alias of a SUM clausules, i posted the full query now

Comment: Note `IF(FIND_IN_SET(...), 1, 0)` is equalivalent to `FIND_IN_SET(...)` as that returns 1 or 0. An effort into removing comma separated columns of values and 3 "numbers_line"  columns into separate table(s) would reduce the complexity of this question, and probably a number of other queries on the same table.

Comment: According to [mysql manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), `FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist) Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the string list strlist consisting of N substrings`